# How to import/transfer md file to javascript string?

Tags: node.js, markdown

I'm curios is it possible to import md(mark down file) file in nodejs and use it as a string?

Question is very simple, how to use md file as a string in javascript (that's all)

Comment: Sure it is. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried several methods, spent like 1 hour on this task. still no luck :(

Comment: What methods? Post the relevant code here. It's like going to your doctor and saying "it hurts". They can't help without _relevant_ details.

Comment: What!? I Said how to import md (markdown file) in nodejs, and use it as a string. Not like "help, my code doesn't work"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. This way u can import md file and use it as a string

```
import {readFileSync} from 'fs'

const markdownContent = readFileSync('apps/express/netlify/CHANGELOG.md', 'utf-8')
console.log(markdownContent, '||1||')
console.log('|||||||')
console.log(JSON.stringify(console.log(markdownContent)), ' heeeere')
```